# DaggerIssueRegistry does not specify a vendor

Tags: android, dagger-2

I get the following build warning, when rebuilding my project.

`dagger.lint.DaggerIssueRegistry in /Users/chris/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/22f4fe0fa52b41738da6fdd077b3882e/transformed/jetified-dagger-lint-aar-2.35.1/jars/lint.jar does not specify a vendor; see IssueRegistry#vendor`

Dagger version is 2.35.1.

Google doesn't give much in the way of useful answers either. Any ideas on a potential fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigations in the dagger git repo, I came across [this issue](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/2582).

It looks like this is a known problem that has a fix but due to uptake on AGP 7 and above, it's not possible currently to release.

**EDIT ** According to https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/2582#issuecomment-1154543399, version 2.41 and later should contain the fix